# Como é o processo do 'Two way data binding' com JS puro?

Tags: javascript

Hoje em dia os framework's javaScript são populares, como React, Vue e Angular.

Eles trabalham com **Two-Way Data Binding** que é uma mão na roda para o desenvolvedor.

Como este processo é feito? Existe alguma forma simples para realizar este processo?

Gostaria de algo didático se possível.

Comment: Criei um exemplo aqui: https://github.com/andreustimm/knockoutjs_localforage talvez possa te ajudar no seu entendimento. Ele utiliza Knockout JS e Localforage (offline)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entenda, fazer um `Two-Way Data Binding` do nada é bem mais complicado do que parece, afinal você terá de prever todos os cenários, então aconselho fortemente que não tente o fazer, e utilize uma ferramenta como o `VueJS` ou `React`.

No exemplo abaixo, o `Two-Way Data Binding` envolve apenas duas `diretivas`, no caso `data-html` e `data-value`, onde estamos pressupondo que elas serão um `span` e um `input[type='text']`. Em um cenário real, você teria de tratar o comportamento destas diretivas em diferentes tipos de HTMLElement, como um `select` ou `input[type='radio']`

O segundo ponto, é que temos de alterar o objeto que servirá de modelo, sobrescrevendo os seus `get` e `set`.

Abaixo segue um exemplo funcional, mas tenha em mente, o mesmo está muito longe de ser algo maduro o suficiente para ser adotado como um Blibioteca.

```js
// definindo um modelo
var model = {
  teste1: 'Hello World',
  teste2: 'Olá Mundo'
};

(function () {
  // buscando todos os HTMLElement com a diretiva data-value
  var values = document.querySelectorAll("[data-value]")
  // buscando todos os HTMLElement com a diretiva data-html
  var htmls = document.querySelectorAll("[data-html]")
  // criando um indice para os HTMLElements com a diretiva data-value
  values = [].reduce.call(values, function (values, value) {
    if (!values[value.dataset.value])
      values[value.dataset.value] = [];
    values[value.dataset.value].push(value)
    return values
  }, {})
  // criando um indice para os HTMLElements com a diretiva data-html
  htmls = [].reduce.call(htmls, function (htmls, html) {
    if (!htmls[html.dataset.html])
      htmls[html.dataset.html] = [];
    htmls[html.dataset.html].push(html)
    return htmls
  }, {})  
  
  // criando um evento para os HTMLElements com a diretiva data-value
  // quando o mesmo for atualizado pelo Usuario, deverá refletir no modelo
  // ao refletir no modelo, este deverá ser propagado para o restante da pagina.
  var onValueInput = function (evt) {
    model[this.key] = this.input.value
  }
  Object.keys(values).forEach(function (key) {
    var inputs = values[key]
    inputs.forEach(function (input) {
      input.addEventListener("input", onValueInput.bind({ key, input }))
    })
  })
  // modificando as propriedades de acesso do modelo
  Object.keys(model).forEach(function (key) {
    var _value = model[key]
    Object.defineProperty(model, key, {
      // get: retorna o valor para de uma determinada propriedade do modelo
      get: function () {
        return _value;
      },
      // set: ao setar algum valor no modelo, deve se propagar o mesmo para os HTMLElements
      // com diretivas associadas a esta propriedade
      set: function (value) {
        _value = value
        if (values[key]) {
          var inputs = values[key]
          inputs.forEach(function (input) {
            input.value = _value
          })
        }
        if (htmls[key]) {
          var spans = htmls[key]
          spans.forEach(function (span) {
            span.textContent = _value
          })
        }
      }
    })
    // atualizando a pagina com os valores iniciais
    model[key] = _value
  })
})();

// atualizando os valores do modelo após 5 segundos (apenas para demonstrar o 2-way data binding)
window.setTimeout(function () {
  model.teste1 += " - deprecated"
  model.teste2 += " - descontinuado"
}, 5000)
```

```html
<input type="text" data-value="teste1" />
<br />
<span data-html="teste1"></span>
<br />
<input type="text" data-value="teste2" />
<br />
<span data-html="teste2"></span>
<br />
<br />
Recaptulando, Os textos são <span data-html="teste1"></span> e <span data-html="teste2"></span>
```

Answer (score 3):

***Two-way data binding*** ou **ligação bidirecional** significa basicamente o seguinte:

- Quando os dados/elementos da **interface** *(frontend)* do usuário são atualizados/incluídos

  - As alterações são propagadas para  o **modelo** *(backend/controller/javascript)*
  - Para que passe pela rega de negócios e se necessário grave no banco de dados
- Quando as propriedades no **modelo** *(backend)* são incluídas/atualizadas

  - O mesmo acontece com a **interface** *(frontend/layout/html)* do usuário
  - Para que o usuário visualize os dados alterados/gravados pelo sistema

---

Exemplo **simples**  usando apenas uma função de poucas linhas com **`JavaScript`** **puro:**

```js
twoWay = function(event) {
  var elem = document.getElementsByClassName(event.currentTarget.className);
  for(var key in elem){
    elem[key].value = event.currentTarget.value;
  }
}
```

```html
<title>Exemplo Two Way data binding</title>
<body style="background: whitesmoke;">

  Nome : <input type="text" class="username" onkeyup="twoWay(event);" >
  <input type="text" class="username" onkeyup="twoWay(event);"> <br>
  
  Idade : <input type="text" class="idade" onkeyup="twoWay(event);" >
  <input type="text" class="idade" onkeyup="twoWay(event);">
  <input type="text" class="idade" onkeyup="twoWay(event);">
</body>
```

---

#### Outro exemplo (apenas código):

- https://gist.github.com/emchateau/e3057c7e76a50d895e98b6d6bd7404ac

---

#### Referencias:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45490004/2-way-data-binding-in-javascript